# How can i plot all the individual histograms in a dataframe at once Using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, data-visualization, seaborn

I have a dataframe with multiple columns and I want to plot them all at once, I tried using a for loop I keep getting errors

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this :

```
    for i in range(n_samples):
    pyplot.subplot(n_rows, n_columns, 1 + i)
    pyplot.axis('off')
    pyplot.imshow(Dataframe[i,:,:,:])
```

**n_samples** = Number of your samples you want to plot (number of histograms)

**Dataframe** = for example a numpy array which you can call with `[i,:,..,:]`

**n_rows** = Number of rows you want, but n_rows*n_colums=n_samples

**n_columns** = Number of rows you want, but n_rows*n_colums=n_samples

For example wrap it to:

```
    for i in range(n_samples):
    pyplot.subplot(n_rows, n_samples, 1 + i)
    pyplot.axis('off')
    pyplot.imshow(Dataframe[i,:,:,:])
```

For example:

```
n_colums=3, n_rows=2, n_samples=6
```

[image]